# Градиент Rectangle() Swift

Tags: swift, color

цель такая:

- Раскрасить прямоугольник в градиент (От purple до teal) C Левого Края до Правого.
  Ниже кусочек кода который выдает ошибку и сама ошибка:

```
             Rectangle()
                .frame(width: progress, height: 8)
                .foregroundColor(LinearGradient(colors: [.purple, .teal], startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .leading))
                .cornerRadius(10)
```

> > > Cannot convert value of type 'LinearGradient' to expected argument type 'Color?'

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать, обратите внимание я еще поменял `cornerRadius`, он должен быть по идее не больше чем половина высоты

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 8)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.purple, .teal], startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .leading))
            .cornerRadius(4)
    }
}
```